# trouble display json object in html

Tags: json

i am trying to display a notification of an error message but what i am seeing is the actual json data with formatting.

```
notificationMsg({ text: data.responseText, type: 'error', hide: false });
```

result displayed is:

> {"Title":"Error","Message":"Error with Account login","Type":3,"Data":null,"Hide":false,"IsClientMessage":true,"TypeString":"error"}

i would like for it to appear like such:

> Error
>   Error with Account login

i tried:

```
notificationMsg({ text: JSON.parse(data.responseText), type: 'error', hide: false });
```

but the outcome was

```
[Object Object]
```

How can i properly display the error message without the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse JSON try following code

```
  objResposneText = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
  notificationMsg({ text: objResposneText.Title, type: 'error', hide: false });
  notificationMsg({ text: objResposneText.Message, type: 'error', hide: false });
```

or for single notification message

```
  notificationMsg({ text: objResposneText.Title + " " + objResposneText.Message, type: 'error', hide: false });
```

Comment: try adding `var objResposneText = JSON.parse(data.responseText);` before `notificationMsg({ text: objResposneText.Title, type: 'error', hide: false });`

Comment: yes i realized that i missed that so i went ahead and added it - thanks for your help!!